# ListView set dummy row height

Tags: listview, javafx

A minor graphical annoyance but I have a ListView set to display custom objects with a set height more than the default. I attempted to use `setFixedCellSize()` which works perfectly in most uses but in one case the cell heights for some cells may grow and shrink based on user interaction.

```
class Example extends Label {
    private boolean change = true;
    public Example(String text) {
        super(text);
        setMinHeight(150);
        setPrefHeight(150);
        setMaxHeight(150);
        Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink("Change");
        setGraphic(link);
        link.setOnAction(ae -> {
            change = !change;
            if(change) {
                setMinHeight(80);
                setPrefHeight(80);
                setMaxHeight(80);
            } else {
                setMinHeight(180);
                setPrefHeight(180);
                setMaxHeight(180);
            }
        });
    }
}

ListView<Node> list = new ListView<>();
list.setFixedCellSize(150);
list.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
list.getItems().addAll(new Example("Hello world"), new Example("12345"));
```

In my example above, the label changes height when the Hyperlink is clicked. It no longer does this when `setFixedCellSize()` is added. Is there another way achieve the same effect of changing the dummy rows but allow the custom Nodes to change height?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set a custom cell factory which sets your desired height based on the state of the cell (I'm assuming by "dummy cells" you mean empty cells):

```
ListView<String> lv = new ListView<>();
lv.setCellFactory(lst ->
        new ListCell<String>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setPrefHeight(45.0);
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    setPrefHeight(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
                    setText(item);
                }
            }
        });
lv.getItems().addAll("Hello", "World");
```

This will cause non-empty cells to have their preferred size (according to the content, in this case it's just the string), while empty cells will have their preferred size as 45.

[image: Illustration]